# Find the values of $\alpha$ such that the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Given the function $$f_a(x,y)=\begin{cases}y^\alpha \frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}\ \ \ \ \text{ for }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ for }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

with $\alpha=1,2,3,\dots$, for which values of $\alpha$ is the function continuous on the plane?

So I tried going with the fact that if it has to be continuous then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y^\alpha \frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}=0$$ so I tried approaching with polar coordinates: $$\lim_{r\to 0} r^\alpha \sin^\alpha \theta\frac{\sin(r^2 \cos\theta\sin\theta)}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\sin^\alpha \theta\frac{\sin(r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)}{r^{2-\alpha}}$$ so then I concluded that if $\alpha\geq 2$, the limit would be $0\ \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ hence would be always continuous and then continued with $\alpha<2$ with the limit and doing l'hôpital maybe but it doesn't seem to be ending anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1.$ Btw, beware: not $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ ($\alpha$ has to be an integer for $y^\alpha$ to be defined even when $y<0$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to demonstrate the limit $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {x\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2} $ with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414658/how-to-demonstrate-the-limit-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-x-sinxy)

Comment: @AnneBauval are you suggesting me to try with epsilon-delta to try then to use the known limit of sine?

Comment: No, the known limit (of $\frac{\sin t}t$) was my first thought (to erase the function $\sin$ in the limit), but that duplicate gives a smarter method (with or [without epsilon-delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2414666/386889)). Note that you already proved the continuity for $\alpha=2,3,\dots$ hence there only remains to prove it for $\alpha=1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval oh that's true, so then since for $\alpha=1$ by doing l'hôpitals rule, the limit is also always 0, hence it is continuous $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes for the conclusion, but l'Hôpital is really overkill here (like very often). I even don't (want to) know how you would write its use here. Simply use the same upper bound as in the proposed duplicate. Note also that once you have proved the continuity for $\alpha=1,$ the continuity for $\alpha>1$ follows. Hence actually, no need of polar coordinates either.

Comment: I suggest applying $|\sin(xy)|\le |xy|\le {x^2+y^2\over 2}.$